# DraggableScrollableSheet with two scrollable bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have tried all the possible combinations with the stacks and columns sliver...  but in the end I cannot create this ui as shown in the image below

[DraggableScrollableSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atHSK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with a simple DraggableScrollableSheet

```
class Delegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(color: Colors.black,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),

      child: Text("Directions",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 16),),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 40;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 30;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with
    TickerProviderStateMixin{
late double _height;
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _height=10;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: Container(color: Colors.red,height: 100,width: 100,)),
      bottomSheet: NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
        onNotification: (dr){
          _height=dr.extent>0.5?  220: 10;
          log('fl $_height');
          return true;
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
FlutterLogo(size:500),
            DraggableScrollableSheet(
              minChildSize: 0.4,initialChildSize: 0.4,
              builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
                return ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(22.0)),

                child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      //this section is a list
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:_height==0?20:_height,
                              left: 8.0) ,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        child:CustomScrollView(
                          controller: scrollController,
                          slivers: [
                            SliverPersistentHeader(pinned: true,floating: true,
                            delegate: Delegate(),),
                          SliverList(
                            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context,index)=>Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                      color: Color(0xffF55A00)),
                                  height: 5,
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        bottom: 10),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut.",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 12),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),)
                          ],
                        )
                      ),

                      //this section is a header
                      AnimatedSize(
                        reverseDuration:  Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        duration:   Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        vsync: this,curve: Curves.ease,
                        child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:30,left: 8.0,)
                          ,color: Colors.black,
                          height: _height,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(controller: scrollController,
                            child:Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text("French Toast with Berries ",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                                    color: Colors.white),),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Icon(Icons.favorite,color: Color(0xffF55A00),),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Text("120 calories ",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,
                                  color:Color(0xffF55A00) ,
                                ),textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
                                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.access_time,size: 14,
                                          color: Colors.white60 ,),
                                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                                        Text("10 mins",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3!.copyWith(
                                            fontSize: 14,color: Colors.white60
                                        ),),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 20,),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.local_dining_sharp,size: 14,color:  Colors.white60,),
                                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                                        Text("5  Serving",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3!.copyWith(
                                            fontSize: 14,color: Colors.white60
                                        ),),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Divider(color: Colors.white54,),
                                Text("Ingredients",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Colors.white),),
                                SizedBox(height:50 ,width: double.maxFinite,
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                    itemBuilder: (context,i)=>Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                      child: Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                            color: Colors.white)
                                        ,height: 30,width: 30,child: FlutterLogo(size: 10,),),),
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    itemCount: 10,),
                                ),
                              ],),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      SingleChildScrollView(controller: scrollController,
                        child:  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 90,left: 90,top:5),
                          child: Container(height: 8,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color:Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)
                            ),),),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the one you need is exactly DraggableScrollableSheet, but you need to customize it a little bit.
As the image you provided, you give the container child of this widget a height with MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * yourRatio
Then when the user clicks at the centered top-notch bar, the height of DraggableScrollableSheet will be adjusted like 95% of the height of this screen.

And you can also use GestureDetector to find the height user scroll. If you want the DraggableScrollableSheet be always the same like the first picture or just leave it behind and let user scroll down to close this one.

[edited]: Hi I just figured out this package sliding_up_panel , just try it .

Comment: I solved the problem by DraggableScrollableSheet that contains a stack  with CustomScrollView , AnimatedSize as children and NotificationListener as a parent widget